# Create servlet context without autowiring in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, singleton

I have a singleton class and one its private members is ServletContext object.
I made it singleton to remove spring dependency since I am trying to write in pure java code.

```
public class Utils {

    private static Utils utils = null;

    public Utils() {
        // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }

    public synchronized static Utils getInstance() {
        if (utils == null) {
            utils = new Utils();
        }
        return utils;
    }

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void makeUtils() {
        // output csv path
        String outputFile = servletContext.getRealPath("/util");
    }
}
```

But here `servletContext` will be null because I am creating the object of `Utils` class wherever I needed manually. Not by using @Autowired. So spring is not injecting the dependency. How can I solve this.

Comment: Make a Spring singleton bean of type `Utils` and inject it everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Autowired` is a spring annotation.

If you want something to happen in response to that annotation, then you need to use spring. If you want to remove the dependency on spring, then you can't use `Autowired`. You need to pick one - are you depending on spring for your wiring, or not?

Some solutions you could follow:

## Using Spring

#### Make `Utils` a spring bean and inject it

Put `Utils` into your spring context (bean factory) and then inject it (using `@Autowired`, or another wiring strategy) into every other class that wants to use it.

#### Make `Utils` a spring bean and look it up.

There's really not much reason to do it this way, but if you want, you can get access to your spring bean factory (probably via the `ApplicationContext`) and lookup a bean by type using `BeanFactory.getBean(Class<T>)`

#### Use Spring to autowire an existing `Utils` object

Again, there's not many good reasons to do this, but if you have an instance of `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` (which you can get via `ApplicationContext`) then you can call `autowireBean(Object existingBean)` to get spring to wire up your `@Autowired` fields.

*Note: My method/class references are from Spring 3.2 because it's what's open in my IDE right now. You may need to make adjustments if you have a different spring version)*

## Without Spring

#### Instantiate `Utils` within a *Servlet* (or Listener)

Create a `configure` method on `Utils` that takes the `ServletContext`.
Inside a `Servlet` (or a `ServletContextListener`) call that `configure` method to set the `servletContext` field on `Utils`.

#### Store a static global `ServletContext`

Create an object like `ServletContextHolder` that has a static field on which you can store the `ServletContext`
Inside a `Servlet` (or a `ServletContextListener`) call the `setContext` method on that holder set the `servletContext` field.
Inside `Utils` call `ServletContextHolder.getContext()`

Comment: Yes. I adopted Without Spring section. In a @Postconstruct method, I set the value of Utils.servletContext object